I can't seem to send push notifications via my Spring Boot WebSocket API to my client
I'm trying to create a Spring Boot WebSocket server implementation and a react client. I'm having problems though. I'm new to WebSockets. I'm using an html test file and a small node server for testing. When I connect to the server it seems to work, but when I try sending messages through my NotificationController from the server to the client, I don't get any. I've checked the network tab as well.
Here is my code:
package com.consudo.streamguard.config;

import java.security.Principal;

public class AdvertiserPrincipal implements Principal {

    private final String name;

    public AdvertiserPrincipal(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}


package com.consudo.streamguard.config;

import com.consudo.streamguard.entity.Advertiser;
import com.consudo.streamguard.service.AuthTokenService;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.server.ServerHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.http.server.ServerHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketHandler;
import org.springframework.web.socket.server.HandshakeInterceptor;

import java.net.URI;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Map;

@Component
public class CustomHandshakeInterceptor implements HandshakeInterceptor {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomHandshakeInterceptor.class);

    @Autowired
    private AuthTokenService authTokenService;

    @Override
    public boolean beforeHandshake(ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response,
                                   WebSocketHandler wsHandler, Map<String, Object> attributes) throws Exception {
        log.info("CustomHandshakeInterceptor: beforeHandshake");

        URI uri = request.getURI();
        String query = uri.getQuery();
        String token = null;

        if (query != null) {
            for (String param : query.split("&")) {
                String[] keyValue = param.split("=");
                if (keyValue.length == 2 && keyValue[0].equals("token")) {
                    token = keyValue[1];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (token != null) {
            log.debug("Extraherat token från query parameter: {}", token);
            try {
                byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(token);
                String decodedToken = new String(decodedBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                log.debug("Dekodad token: {}", decodedToken);

                Advertiser advertiser = authTokenService.getAdvertiserByToken(decodedToken);
                if (advertiser != null) {
                    attributes.put("principal", new AdvertiserPrincipal(advertiser.getAdvertiserId().toString()));
                    log.info("Autentiserad advertiserId: {}", advertiser.getAdvertiserId());
                    return true;
                } else {
                    log.warn("Ogiltigt token för WebSocket-anslutning");
                    response.setStatusCode(org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
                    return false;
                }
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                log.error("Misslyckades med att avkoda token från Base64: {}", e.getMessage());
                response.setStatusCode(org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            log.warn("Saknas token i WebSocket CONNECT");
            response.setStatusCode(org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterHandshake(ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response,
                               WebSocketHandler wsHandler, Exception exception) {
        log.info("CustomHandshakeInterceptor: afterHandshake");
    }
}

package com.consudo.streamguard.config;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.ChannelRegistration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.*;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSocketConfig.class);

    @Autowired
    private CustomHandshakeInterceptor customHandshakeInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic", "/queue");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        config.setUserDestinationPrefix("/user");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws")
                .addInterceptors(customHandshakeInterceptor)
                .setAllowedOriginPatterns("http://localhost:3000")
                .withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
    }
}

package com.consudo.streamguard.config;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.user.SimpUser;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.user.SimpUserRegistry;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.SessionConnectEvent;
import org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.SessionDisconnectEvent;

@Component
public class WebSocketEventListener {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSocketEventListener.class);

    @Autowired
    private SimpUserRegistry simpUserRegistry;

    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate;

    @EventListener
    public void handleWebSocketConnectListener(SessionConnectEvent event) {
        log.info("WebSocket Connect Event: {}", event.getMessage());

        if (event.getUser() != null) {
            String username = event.getUser().getName();
            SimpUser user = simpUserRegistry.getUser(username);
            if (user != null) {
                log.info("Användare ansluten: {}", user.getName());
                String confirmationMessage = "Välkommen, Advertiser " + user.getName() + "! Anslutningen är upprättad.";
                messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(user.getName(), "/queue/notifications", confirmationMessage);
                log.info("Skickade bekräftelse till Advertiser: {}", user.getName());
            } else {
                log.warn("Användaren {} kunde inte hittas i SimpUserRegistry.", username);
            }
        } else {
            log.warn("SessionConnectEvent utan user information.");
        }
    }

    @EventListener
    public void handleWebSocketDisconnectListener(SessionDisconnectEvent event) {
        log.info("WebSocket Disconnect Event: {}", event.getMessage());

        if (event.getUser() != null) {
            String username = event.getUser().getName();
            log.info("Användare frånkopplad: {}", username);
        } else {
            log.warn("SessionDisconnectEvent utan user information.");
        }
    }
}

package com.consudo.streamguard.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

@Controller
public class NotificationController {

    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate;

    public void sendNotificationToAdvertiser(String advertiserId, String content) {
        messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(advertiserId, "/queue/notifications", content);
    }
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>WebSocket Push Notification Test</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sockjs-client@1/dist/sockjs.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@stomp/stompjs@6.1.2/bundles/stomp.umd.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>WebSocket Push Notification Test</h1>

    <div>
        <h2>Mottagna Meddelanden</h2>
        <ul id="messages"></ul>
    </div>

    <script>
        let stompClient = null;

        function connect() {
            const authToken = 'NmRlZjhkMWUtNjVmZS00MzFhLWI3NDAtMTFlNThkNDAyMTg5'; 

            const socket = new SockJS(`http://localhost:8082/ws?token=${authToken}`);
            stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);

            stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
                console.log('Ansluten: ' + frame);

                stompClient.subscribe('/user/queue/notifications', function(message) {
                    console.log('Mottaget meddelande:', message.body);
                    showMessage(message.body);
                });

            }, function(error) {
                console.error('STOMP-fel: ' + error);
            });
        }

        function showMessage(message) {
            const messages = document.getElementById('messages');
            const li = document.createElement('li');
            li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message));
            messages.appendChild(li);
        }

        window.onload = connect;
    </script>
</body>
</html>

Here is the serverlog while connecting:
2024-10-27T17:34:44.052+01:00 DEBUG 19464 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/ws/info?token=NmRlZjhkMWUtNjVmZS00MzFhLWI3NDAtMTFlNThkNDAyMTg5&t=1730046883944", parameters={masked}
2024-10-27T17:34:44.054+01:00 TRACE 19464 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.w.s.s.s.WebSocketHandlerMapping      : Mapped to HandlerExecutionChain with [org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.support.SockJsHttpRequestHandler@379af509] and 1 interceptors
2024-10-27T17:34:44.056+01:00 DEBUG 19464 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.w.s.s.t.h.DefaultSockJsService       : Processing transport request: GET http://localhost:8082/ws/info?token=NmRlZjhkMWUtNjVmZS00MzFhLWI3NDAtMTFlNThkNDAyMTg5&t=1730046883944
2024-10-27T17:34:44.057+01:00 DEBUG 19464 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2024-10-27T17:34:44.063+01:00 DEBUG 19464 --- [nio-8082-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/ws/055/hq5xuj13/websocket?token=NmRlZjhkMWUtNjVmZS00MzFhLWI3NDAtMTFlNThkNDAyMTg5", parameters={masked}
2024-10-27T17:34:44.064+01:00 TRACE 19464 --- [nio-8082-exec-2] o.s.w.s.s.s.WebSocketHandlerMapping      : Mapped to HandlerExecutionChain with [org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.support.SockJsHttpRequestHandler@379af509] and 1 interceptors
2024-10-27T17:34:44.064+01:00 DEBUG 19464 --- [nio-8082-exec-2] o.s.w.s.s.t.h.DefaultSockJsService       : Processing transport request: GET http://localhost:8082/ws/055/hq5xuj13/websocket?token=NmRlZjhkMWUtNjVmZS00MzFhLWI3NDAtMTFlNThkNDAyMTg5
2024-10-27T17:34:44.064+01:00  INFO 19464 --- [nio-8082-exec-2] c.c.s.config.CustomHandshakeInterceptor  : CustomHandshakeInterceptor: beforeHandshake
2024-10-27T17:34:44.064+01:00 DEBUG 19464 --- [nio-8082-exec-2] c.c.s.config.CustomHandshakeInterceptor  : Extraherat token från query parameter: NmRlZjhkMWUtNjVmZS00MzFhLWI3NDAtMTFlNThkNDAyMTg5
2024-10-27T17:34:44.065+01:00 DEBUG 19464 --- [nio-8082-exec-2] c.c.s.config.CustomHandshakeInterceptor  : Dekodad token: 6def8d1e-65fe-431a-b740-11e58d402189
2024-10-27T17:34:44.100+01:00  INFO 19464 --- [nio-8082-exec-2] c.c.s.config.CustomHandshakeInterceptor  : Autentiserad advertiserId: 15
2024-10-27T17:34:44.103+01:00 TRACE 19464 --- [nio-8082-exec-2] o.s.w.s.s.s.DefaultHandshakeHandler      : Processing request http://localhost:8082/ws/055/hq5xuj13/websocket?token=NmRlZjhkMWUtNjVmZS00MzFhLWI3NDAtMTFlNThkNDAyMTg5 with headers=[host:"localhost:8082", connection:"Upgrade", pragma:"no-cache", cache-control:"no-cache", user-agent:"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/129.0.0.0 Safari/537.36", upgrade:"websocket", origin:"http://localhost:3000", sec-websocket-version:"13", accept-encoding:"gzip, deflate, br, zstd", accept-language:"sv-SE,sv;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7", cookie:"Idea-cf53348f=3e446477-f4ca-4855-8bca-e4545010a8f3; JSESSIONID=70F7C17546E860253CA475974589BE7A", sec-websocket-key:"9VxgWBWtjS3dkkfPU13J9g==", sec-websocket-extensions:"permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits"]
2024-10-27T17:34:44.104+01:00 TRACE 19464 --- [nio-8082-exec-2] o.s.w.s.s.s.DefaultHandshakeHandler      : Upgrading to WebSocket, subProtocol=null, extensions=[]
2024-10-27T17:34:44.120+01:00  INFO 19464 --- [nio-8082-exec-2] c.c.s.config.CustomHandshakeInterceptor  : CustomHandshakeInterceptor: afterHandshake
2024-10-27T17:34:44.120+01:00 DEBUG 19464 --- [nio-8082-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 101 SWITCHING_PROTOCOLS
2024-10-27T17:34:44.130+01:00 DEBUG 19464 --- [nio-8082-exec-2] s.w.s.h.LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator : New WebSocketServerSockJsSession[id=hq5xuj13]
2024-10-27T17:34:44.134+01:00 TRACE 19464 --- [nio-8082-exec-2] o.s.w.s.adapter.NativeWebSocketSession   : Sending TextMessage payload=[o], byteCount=1, last=true], StandardWebSocketSession[id=5f88dfa6-79d1-d37a-c727-72c16fb74da0, uri=ws://localhost:8082/ws/055/hq5xuj13/websocket?token=NmRlZjhkMWUtNjVmZS00MzFhLWI3NDAtMTFlNThkNDAyMTg5]
2024-10-27T17:34:44.137+01:00 TRACE 19464 --- [nio-8082-exec-2] s.w.s.s.t.s.WebSocketServerSockJsSession : Scheduled heartbeat in session hq5xuj13

This is me trying to trigger a manual sending of a message to the client through a test rest controller:
package com.consudo.streamguard.controller;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class NotificationTestController {

    @Autowired
    private NotificationController notificationController;

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NotificationTestController.class);

    @GetMapping("/testmess")
    public String sendTestNotification() {
        String advertiserId = "15";
        String message = "Hej från servern!";

        log.info("Anropar sendNotificationToAdvertiser med advertiserId: {} och message: {}", advertiserId, message);

        notificationController.sendNotificationToAdvertiser(advertiserId, message);

        return "Testnotis skickad till Advertiser " + advertiserId;
    }
}

2024-10-27T17:36:49.150+01:00 TRACE 19464 --- [MessageBroker-9] s.w.s.s.t.s.WebSocketServerSockJsSession : Preparing to write SockJsFrame content='h'
2024-10-27T17:36:49.151+01:00 TRACE 19464 --- [MessageBroker-9] s.w.s.s.t.s.WebSocketServerSockJsSession : Writing SockJsFrame content='h'
2024-10-27T17:36:49.156+01:00 TRACE 19464 --- [MessageBroker-9] o.s.w.s.adapter.NativeWebSocketSession   : Sending TextMessage payload=[h], byteCount=1, last=true], StandardWebSocketSession[id=5f88dfa6-79d1-d37a-c727-72c16fb74da0, uri=ws://localhost:8082/ws/055/hq5xuj13/websocket?token=NmRlZjhkMWUtNjVmZS00MzFhLWI3NDAtMTFlNThkNDAyMTg5]
2024-10-27T17:36:49.158+01:00 TRACE 19464 --- [MessageBroker-9] s.w.s.s.t.s.WebSocketServerSockJsSession : Cancelling heartbeat in session hq5xuj13
2024-10-27T17:36:49.160+01:00 TRACE 19464 --- [MessageBroker-9] s.w.s.s.t.s.WebSocketServerSockJsSession : Scheduled heartbeat in session hq5xuj13
2024-10-27T17:36:50.121+01:00 DEBUG 19464 --- [nio-8082-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/testmess", parameters={}
2024-10-27T17:36:50.122+01:00 DEBUG 19464 --- [nio-8082-exec-5] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.consudo.streamguard.controller.NotificationTestController#sendTestNotification()
2024-10-27T17:36:50.139+01:00  INFO 19464 --- [nio-8082-exec-5] c.c.s.c.NotificationTestController       : Anropar sendNotificationToAdvertiser med advertiserId: 15 och message: Hej från servern!
2024-10-27T17:36:50.143+01:00 TRACE 19464 --- [nio-8082-exec-5] o.s.m.s.u.UserDestinationMessageHandler  : No active sessions for user destination: /user/15/queue/notifications
2024-10-27T17:36:50.147+01:00 DEBUG 19464 --- [nio-8082-exec-5] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Using 'text/plain', given [*/*] and supported [text/plain, */*, application/json, application/*+json]
2024-10-27T17:36:50.147+01:00 DEBUG 19464 --- [nio-8082-exec-5] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Writing ["Testnotis skickad till Advertiser 15"]
2024-10-27T17:36:50.149+01:00 DEBUG 19464 --- [nio-8082-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK

Anyone got any idea at all? Like I said, I'm new to WebSockets so I'm kinda clueless.
